# Errors Loading a Network File into a Stream in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, stream

I have a Classic ASP website that currently loads PDF files from a local directory and writes them to the Response. I create a stream and use LoadFromFile to pull the data. This has worked well for years, but we now want to delete the local files and pull from a network "\" drive, where all of our .NET sites pull the files from.

We do this in our .NET sites with no problem, but I cannot figure out how to open a network file from Classic ASP and load it into a stream. Nothing I have tried seems to recognize the "\server\directory\file" as a valid path.

So, just to be as clear as possible, this is what we do:

1. Pull a DocID from the QueryString.
2. Pass the DocID as a parameter to a SQL proc to pull the path to the file (In the current ASP page it pulls a local path, in .NET it pulls a network path. In our new ASP page it will now pull a network path).
3. We create a stream and load the file into it (this is the part that does not work in Classic ASP if the path is "\" instead of "D:\").
4. We change the Response.ContentType to "application/pdf".
5. We Response.BinaryWrite and Flush the Response.

The result is the page displays the PDF with no indication of the file name or location.

Adding partial code:

```
' sets the Cache-Control HTTP header to prevent proxy caching
Response.CacheControl = "Private"
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Clear

sDocID = Request.QueryString("DocID")
sSQL = "exec Get_DocData '" & sDocID & "'"

Set rsDoc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsDoc.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 1
'
' sPath = \\server\directory\filename.ext
' sFileName = filename.ext
'
sPath = rsDoc.Fields("DocPath").Value
sFileName = rDoc.Fields("DocDescription").Value

rsDoc.Close
Set rsDoc = Nothing

'sPath = Replace(sPath,"\\<svr>\<dir>","Z:")

If sPath <> "" Then
    Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        oStream.LoadFromFile sPath
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & sFileName & """"
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8"    
        Do while not oStream.EOS
            Response.BinaryWrite oStream.read(3670016)
            Response.Flush
        Loop
        oStream.Close
        Set oStream = Nothing
Else
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        'Response.Write("Invalid Document ID.")
End If

Response.End
```

Comment: probably `\\server\directory\file`

Comment: What are you doing this `sPath = Replace(sPath,"\\<svr>\<dir>","Z:")` for? `ADODB.Stream`'s `.LoadFromFile()` method supports UNC paths so why replace with `Z:`. If you don't have that drive mapped and `sPath` pointing to a valid file resource you will get the error you are encountering. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35000785/edit) and output what `sPath` contains using `Response.Write sPath: Response.End`.

Comment: Also not to be picky but this `sSQL = "exec Get_DocData '" & sDocID & "'"` is a big no no especially on scripts like this as they tend to used all over a system. [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) will screw you every-time.

Comment: Tried to add this to your comment but meda's answers gone - @BarryKeller Not true, [`LoadFromFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677570(v=vs.85).aspx) does support UNC paths - *"A String value that contains the name of a file to be loaded into the Stream. FileName can contain any valid path and name in [**UNC format**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). If the specified file does not exist, a run-time error occurs."*

Comment: Like @Lashane has mentioned I don't see where you apply `sFileName` to the `sPath` variable before attempting to open the file using `LoadFromFile()`? Might explain the File Not Found error, surely it should be `sPath = sPath & "\" & sFileName`?

Comment: @Lankymart, regarding the `sFileName` not being added to the `sPath`, I get the feeling the former is just a description/title; the `sPath` actually contains the full path, including the filename, right from the outset. Barry, am I correct?

Comment: Regarding the actual question, would `Server.MapPath` be helpful? I get easily confused with UNC vs. URL vs. whatever, so I might be entirely on the wrong, um, path (pun really not intended), but it's worth a mention at least.

Comment: @Martha I would agree that the field sounds more like a description but if that was the case why use `Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & sFileName & """"` to set it as the `filename` in the HTTP header `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: @Martha, you are correct, sFilename is for display purposes only; sPath is the entire path to the file: "\\server\directoryr\filename."

Comment: @Martha Problem with `Server.MapPath()` is it needs to be used with paths relative to the website (virtual directory etc) not sure how that would work on UNC paths unless that path was mapped to a Virtual Directory via a mapped drive, but to be honest seems pointless when `LoadFormFile()` supports UNC paths anyway.

Comment: @BarryKeller Worth clarifying that in the question. Also to avoid all this confusion ideally you need to output the `sPath` variable as I suggested in the comments.

Comment: @Lankymart, I understand the issues with the code. I didn't write it, I just have to move it to the new server and point to the new file location. I don't usually bother to correct the original programmer's issues when it comes to Classic ASP. If I rewrite the site, I would surely do it differently. As to the Content-Disposition header, all I can tell you is it works. Like I said, I did not write this code.

Comment: @Lankymart, Hmmm, I have not been able to get the code to run without error using a UNC with LoadFromFile(); that is my issue.

Comment: And perhaps it is just some sort of permissions issue and all of my attempts to modify code to find another solution have been a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I knew I would feel stupid when I figured this out. As Lankymart commented, the LoadFromFile() does support UNC formatted paths, which lead me to suspect the issue was permission-based and not code-based.

Although our ApplicationPool was running under a general account which had permission to the network drives, the site was not. I simply brought up the site in IIS7, clicked on Basic Settings and used the "Connect as..." button to run the site under the same general account. That corrected my issue. Palm-slapping my head.